# MEF: Import all repositories in the BaseController... Good idea?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mef

is it a good idea to [import()] all repositories in the base-controller using mef, so every child controller will have all reps avaliable?

Are there disadvantages?

Comment: Do you really need all repositories in every controller?

Comment: In my imagination it would be alot easier to import them in the base controller, but no, I dont need them in every controller

Comment: Only import repositories you need than.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's a bad idea

You should only bring in the dependencies that you actually require

Comment: You shouldn't shy away from writing more code if you end up with a better, more maintainable, more testable product where it's easier to see the intent of what is happening. If I was to look at one of your controllers with everything imported, I wouldn't be able to easily tell what it's supposed to do as it takes a dependency on every part of the database

Comment: @user2111892 mark this as the correct answer? Seems good to me. :)